# Python filter Attributes of Interest out of JSON and safe in a new dictionar

Tags: python, json, simplify

I have a big json with 25 items, each item has many attributes like:State, price, description,...
I want to create a new dic with all 25 items but only the attributes i am interested in
my solution works but i would have to write too much manual code:

```
small_dict = {}

for advert_pos, advert in enumerate(data['props']['pageProps']['searchResult']['advertSummaryList']['advertSummary'],0):
    for _, attr in enumerate(advert['attributes']['attribute']):
        if attr['name'] in 'HEADING':
            small_dict[advert_pos] = {'HEADING': attr['values'], 'LOCATION': attr['values']} #here i need to list all attributes of interest

# here i need another block for every aot
for advert_pos, advert in enumerate(data['props']['pageProps']['searchResult']['advertSummaryList']['advertSummary'],0):
    for _, attr in enumerate(advert['attributes']['attribute']):
        if attr['name'] == 'LOCATION':
            small_dict[advert_pos]['LOCATION'] = attr['values']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the giving code here but i would probably use a generator that goes through the json and yields the value if it matches the requirements.

A very simple explanation is that a generator loops through the json and yield pauses the loop and returns that value, then you continue from that spot again to get the next value, this is more efficient on memory aswell since you get one value at a time.

Here is 2 good places to start with generators, i use generators on large json files to loop through all values.

[Generators and yield information](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

[Some examples from wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)